# array walk complex implementation

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my function:

```
function uc_words($str, $destSep='_', $srcSep='_')
{
   return str_replace(' ', $destSep, ucwords(str_replace($srcSep, ' ', $str)));
}
```

What I need is to call every element in `$data` against uc_words with the following parameters: `uc_words($item,' ','_');`

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

As simple as

```
array_walk(
    $data, 
    function(&$value) { 
        $value = uc_words($value, ' ', '_'); 
    } 
);
```